# When getting an answer back from WCF i get a "Strongly-typed" error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>
> Operation 'procWsDocumentAsync' contains a message with parameters. Strongly-typed or untyped message can be paired only with strongly-typed, untyped or void message.

```
    MsgBody.Text = "&lt;OPERVALS&gt;&lt;BOOKINpG_ID&gt;BK170001194&lt;/BOOKING_ID&gt;&lt;DATE&gt;20180828&lt;/DATE&gt;&lt;/OPERVALS&gt;";

    senderId.Text = "DSVWS";
    acessCode.Text = "DSVWS2018";
    operationCode.Text = "BKCARGORECEPTION";
    senderMsgId.Text = "DSV321123134";

    StrMsgBody = MsgBody.Text;
    StrsenderId = senderId.Text;
    StracessCode = acessCode.Text;
    StroperationCode = operationCode.Text;
    StrsenderMsgId = senderMsgId.Text;
}

private async void Submit_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string resposta;
    string resposta1;

    SCPCon.ScpWSIntegrationClient cli = new SCPCon.ScpWSIntegrationClient();
    SCPCon.procWsOperationResponse resp = await cli.procWsOperationAsync

    (
        new SCPCon.procWsOperationRequest   
        {
            ScpOperWsmsgRecUser_1 = new SCPCon.ScpWsmsgRecUser
            {
                wsMsgBody = StrMsgBody,
                wsMsgHeader = new SCPCon.ScpWsmsgHdrRecUser
                {
                   sentDatetime = DateTime.Now,
                   senderId = StrsenderId,
                   accessCode = StracessCode,
                   operationCode = StroperationCode,
                   senderMsgId = StrsenderMsgId,
                }
            }                 
        }
    );
    resposta = resp.ScpOperWsmsgResRecUser_2.resultText;
    resposta1 = resp.ScpOperWsmsgResRecUser_2.resultCode;    
}
```

Comment: I find a similar thread, you could refer to it.https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/98762/consuming-streaming-wcf-service-in-xamarin

Comment: thx for ur comment but it didnt help me at all

Comment: Are You sure that You have newest version of data contract? Did You try update the client class (SCPCon.ScpWSIntegrationClient)?